# Testing the browser popup exceptions from a user click using Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

On my site I've got a user option to check weather the site is added into the popup blocker exceptions list, however since the user clicks the option to test, the popup blocker never activates.

Assuming there is no popup exception for my website, how can I ensure the popup blocker will activate from a clicked DIV? I tried a half second setTimeout() and preventDefault() but no luck:

```
<div id="popupmsg" style="z-index: 999; position:absolute; left:20px; top:370px; background-color: #638910; border:2px solid #97D118; margin-right:20px; padding:5px; color:WHITE;">
<u>Click here to test if popups are enabled for this web-site</u>
</div>
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#popupmsg").click(function() { 
    // setTimeout(function() {
    var popup = window.open("test_popup.html", "", "directories=no,height=150,width=150,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,location=no");
    setTimeout( function() {
        if(!popup || popup.outerHeight === 0) {
            alert("Popup blocker is enabled! Please add this site to your browsers exception list.");
        } else {
            alert("Popup blocker is disabled. Everything should work fine.");
            popup.close();
        } 
    }, 25);
    // }, 500);
    // event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up loading a 'test.html' page on click, which itself automatically tries to load a popup.

If the popup is successful it closes the popup automatically and the test page says everything is good to go, with a return link.

If the popup is unsuccessful the test page gives examples of how to add an exception, with a re-test button (which reloads the 'test.html' page) and a return link for lost people.